# SQL query is using YYYY-DD-MM format, when table is YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, datetime-format

If I run the query:

```
select    startdate, count(*)
from      tablename
where     startdate > '2020-04-06'
```

It only returns value where the startdate is after 4th June 2020. However the dates in the table are in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss.

If I run a getdate() or sysdatetime() it returns 2020-06-16 14:29:29.157 in the correct format.

So why is the query using YYYY-DD-MM? And how do I get it to change by default?

P.S. I'm aware that I could use CONVERT or FORMAT in the query, but as all dates will be in the YYYY-MM-DD format I'd like that to be the default, and not have to write extra code each time.

EDIT: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

EDIT2: I checked with a colleague and the same thing happens to them.

Comment: If you execute the command `DBCC UserOptions`, what is the value of "DateFormat" ? (see https://www.technothirsty.com/change-default-date-format-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Dates and times have no inherent "format", it only matters when turned into strings.

Comment: @Pac0 it returns dmy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That depends on various settings.  You can get around this by removing the hyphens:

```
startdate > '20200406'
```

In SQL Server, this format is always unambiguous, YYYYMMDD.  I prefer the version with the hyphens, because it is more standard.  But if you are dealing with this as an issue I would suggest using the SQL Server unambiguous format.

Comment: And if you need to use the time component, the unambiguous format is `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.nnn]`  (Yes - with hyphens!) Source: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries

Answer (score 2):

You can handle it in two ways:

1. At the session level. you can set format and issue query
2. Use ISO 8601 format (Recommended)

```sql
DECLARE @table table(a datetime)
INSERT INTO @table values('2020-04-06')

SELECT * FROM @table WHERE A = '2020-04-06' -- ISO 8601

set dateformat ymd
SELECT * FROM @table WHERE A = '2020-04-06' -- Format change
```